# Custom protocol handlers Linux, Centos 7 for chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, npapi, protocol-handler

I have developed an application which is invoked on a button click on my website.
I was using **NPAPI** for this task. However recently google has deprecated NPAPI so I called my application using custom protocol handler like `"myapp://"`

On windows my application and handlers are working perfectly fine.

Now I want to do the same in Linux. I need to do this for CentOS preferably 7 and for Chrome web browser.

I did some research but most of the help on web is for firefox but I specifically need it for chrome. My desktop is GNOME based, kindly help please.

Answer (score 18):

To add protocol handler `myapp://` you need to add file `myapp.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications`.
It looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=myapp
Exec=/path/to/your/program %u
Type=Application
Terminal=false
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/myapp;
```

Exec and MimeType are very important.

Then you need to add line

```
x-scheme-handler/myapp=myapp.desktop
```

to file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` under `[Default Applications]`

At the end you will probably need to type command:

```
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
```

For me it was working on all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Please note that `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` is deprecated, please use `~/.config/mimeapps.list` instead, or better yet, run `xdg-mime default <desktopfile> <mimetype>` (replace as needed) instead.